# How to batch blender files？

Tags: python, scripting

I have a problem that has been bothering me. I've been trying to write scripts in blender Python recently. Unfortunately, I'm just a novice. I now have many blender files. How should I batch them? For example, I want to add a new cube in every ative blender file, how do I implement it? Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

For your example, you can use the [Blender Command Line](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/2.79/render/workflows/command_line.html) in a script written in the shell scripting language of your choice, ie, [bash](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bash_(Unix_shell)) on most Unix-like systems; or even Python.  The command line itself would execute a Python script intended for Blender, using something like

```
blender -b ${BLEND_FILE} -P your_python_script.py
```

as a command line, possibly iterating over all of the blend files in a directory, or a list of files you specified.

`your python script` would be a [Blender Python script](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/index.html) that executed the command you wanted and then exited blender.  For something like adding a new cube at the origin it could be as simple as

```py
import bpy
bpy.ops.mesh.primitive_cube_add()
```

Because it's not advised to use a running blender file to modify other blender files, doing it this way, with an external script that invokes Blender to run an internal script that does what you want is probably the best approach.  You could possibly get away with only having to write that script once, having it take the files to operate on as a command line argument.

Writing the external script is OS dependent and out of scope for this Stackexchange.

Comment: Dear friends, I'm glad you can answer my question, which is very useful to me. But writing a single driver seems a little too cumbersome. I wonder if there is a better way to solve this problem, just a Blender's plug-in, which can empty everything in the current scene, load the assets of other blender files, modify them, save them as and overwrite the original blender file. How can I do? Thank you very much!